# Convert String to JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

kindly i want to convert this string to Json using javascript

```
 Result =    {"result":"{\"Response\":\"Success\"}"}
```

i firstly use

```
   Result=Result['result']
```

and i have this

```
   Result= '{"Response":"Success"}'
```

please your help to continue

Comment: you can use JSON.parse

Comment: For your information, `JSON` is already a `String` hence _"Convert String to JSON using Javascript"_ is wrong title.. `'{"Response":"Success"}'` is `JSON` hence `String`, to convert it as `Object`, Use `JSON.parse(YOUR_JSON)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Safely turning a JSON string into an object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45015/safely-turning-a-json-string-into-an-object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [JSON.parse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)

> The JSON.parse() method parses a string as JSON, optionally
>   transforming the value produced by parsing.

```
 Result =    {"result":"{\"Response\":\"Success\"}"};
 Result = JSON.parse(Result['result'])
```